# If there are differences between the behavior on Dartium and the behavior on Chrome

Tags: dart

I'm thinking to develop a web application using dart.
Is it possible that there are differences between the behavior on Dartium and the behavior on Chrome(using compiled JavaScript) ?
I think I should develop on Dartium because of the debuggable but I fear there may be differences of the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are differences.

- Dartium is based on the OpenSource Chromium and is missing some features that Chrome has
- Polymer URLs (imports, asset references) that work in Dartium may not work when build to JavaScript and vice versa. You have to figure out which one work on both. This is work in progress and will probably be fixed but it seems to be a difficult problem.
- there are always some subtle differences

All in all Dartium provides a much superior development experience, therefor it's absoltultly worth using for development.
You have to take some time into account for testing and fixing issues for all the different browsers that you want to support.
Dart does a great work in abstracting differences away but it is not (yet ;-) ) perfect.

Answer (score 5):

Apart the differences between Chromium and Chrome every different behaviour has to be considered as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The major difference is in the behavior of numbers. When compiled to Javascript, numbers behave more like Javascript numbers, which have some semantic differences. Trying to reconcile this without causing an unacceptable performance penalty when compiled to Javascript is a long-standing issue. See https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1533

The editor will give you hints if it can determine that code may behave differently when compiled to Javascript. And for many purposes the differences are not that significant. It's mostly if you exceed 53 bits, where Javascript ints turn into doubles, or if you try to type test (when compiled to Javascript "1 is double" returns true). The worst trouble I've had with it was in code for formatting numbers for different locales, and even that wasn't too bad. I think that developing on Dartium but doing testing on the compiled JS version is a good idea anyay.

Another difference may relate to different levels of implementation of upcoming standards. For example, for a while Dartium had native shadow DOM, but Chrome did not. That was a difference in behavior. But for that you not only need to test compiled to Javascript, you need to test against different browsers and different versions of them.

As in another answer, differences are considered bugs.